How do I completely remove the Continuity Camera from my macOS Sound Input list?
Sometimes when I connect my macOS to an external display and fold the laptop, the mic is not working. So I have to use my iPhone as the mic.
However, when I work directly on the mac without an external display, my screen recording app keeps looking for the iPhone mic (as my iPhone is not by my hand)
This is so annoying, it keeps popping up this on my macOS top-right corner:

How can I completely remove it?

My macOS version 14.4.1 (23E224)
My macOS model Apple M2 Max
Thanks
